Arrays dando erro no Android Studio Koala
Estou fazendo meu primeiro app no Android Studio e, por algum motivo, quando programo as Arrays, o app crasha quando eu tento rodar no meu celular.
Essas é uma das arrays, as outras seguem o mesmo padrão:
public String listaNomes(){

        List<String> minhaLista = Arrays.asList("dinossauro", "baixista", "lobo", "palhaco");
        posicaoLista = 0;
        nomeSelecionado = minhaLista.get(posicaoLista);
        txtPalavraCerta.setText(nomeSelecionado);
        return nomeSelecionado;
    }

Antes de eu programar essas Arrays o app estava abrindo normalmente quando eu rodava no meu celular, mas quando eu as programei o app simplesmente crasha assim que abre e, eu ainda não consegui descobrir o porquê.
Essas arrays são parte importante do projeto, pois elas irão armazenar as palavras que serão embaralhadas para criar as fases.
Eu gostaria de saber se eu estou programando as arrays do jeito certo ou se os erros que estou tendo tem outra causa. Vou postar o código inteiro da minha MainActivity e a parte dos erros do logcat
Eis o código do app:
package com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtTotalPontos, txtDica, txtPalavraCerta;
    private TextView txtLetraMontada1, txtLetraMontada2, txtLetraMontada3, txtLetraMontada4, txtLetraMontada5, txtLetraMontada6, txtLetraMontada7, txtLetraMontada8, txtLetraMontada9, txtLetraMontada10,txtLetraMontada11, txtLetraMontada12, txtLetraMontada13;
    private TextView txtLetraMontada14, txtLetraMontada15, txtLetraMontada16, txtLetraMontada17, txtLetraMontada18, txtLetraMontada19, txtLetraMontada20, txtLetraMontada21, txtLetraMontada22, txtLetraMontada23, txtLetraMontada24, txtLetraMontada25, txtLetraMontada26;

    private String palavraEmbaralhada, letraDigitada, palavraSemEdicao, nomeSelecionado, palavra;

    private Button buttonLetra1, buttonLetra2, buttonLetra3, buttonLetra4, buttonLetra5, buttonLetra6, buttonLetra7, buttonLetra8, buttonLetra9, buttonLetra10, buttonLetra11, buttonLetra12, buttonLetra13;
    private Button buttonLetra14, buttonLetra15, buttonLetra16, buttonLetra17, buttonLetra18, buttonLetra19, buttonLetra20, buttonLetra21, buttonLetra22, buttonLetra23, buttonLetra24, buttonLetra25, buttonLetra26;
    private Button btnEmbaralhar, btnSair, btnJogarNovamente;

    private String ClickBtn1, ClickBtn2, ClickBtn3, ClickBtn4, ClickBtn5, ClickBtn6, ClickBtn7, ClickBtn8, ClickBtn9, ClickBtn10, ClickBtn11, ClickBtn12, ClickBtn13;
    private String ClickBtn14, ClickBtn15, ClickBtn16, ClickBtn17, ClickBtn18, ClickBtn19, ClickBtn20, ClickBtn21, ClickBtn22, ClickBtn23, ClickBtn24, ClickBtn25, ClickBtn26;

    private int posicaoLista;

    private String letra0, letra1, letra2, letra3, letra4, letra5, letra6, letra7, letra8, letra9, letra10, letra11, letra12, letra13, letra14, letra15, letra16, letra17, letra18, letra19, letra20, letra21, letra22, letra23, letra24, letra25;
   @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        novoJogo();

        btnSair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnEmbaralhar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                novoJogo();
            }
        });

        buttonLetra1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ClickBtn1.equals("nao")){
                    ClickBtn1 = "sim";
                    buttonLetra1.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

                }
            }
        });

       buttonLetra2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn2.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn2 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra2.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn3.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn3 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra3.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn4.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn4 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra4.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn5.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn5 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra5.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn6.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn6 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra6.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn7.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn7 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra7.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn8.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn8 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra8.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn9.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn9 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra9.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn10.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn10 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra10.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn11.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn11 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra11.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn12.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn12 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra12.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn13.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn13 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra13.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn14.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn14 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra14.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn15.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn15 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra15.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn16.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn16 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra16.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra17.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn17.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn17 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra17.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra18.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn18.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn18 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra18.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra19.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn19.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn19 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra19.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn20.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn20 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra20.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn21.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn21 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra21.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra22.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn22.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn22 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra22.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra23.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn23.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn23 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra23.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra24.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn24.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn24 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra24.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra25.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn25.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn25 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra25.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });

       buttonLetra26.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(ClickBtn26.equals("nao")){
                   ClickBtn26 = "sim";
                   buttonLetra26.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#0F3A01"));

               }
           }
       });
    }

      private void novoJogo(){
        txtTotalPontos = findViewById(R.id.txtTotalPontos);
        txtDica = findViewById(R.id.txtDica);
        txtPalavraCerta = findViewById(R.id.txtPalavraCerta);

        txtLetraMontada1 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada1);
        txtLetraMontada2 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada2);
        txtLetraMontada3 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada3);
        txtLetraMontada4 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada4);
        txtLetraMontada5 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada5);

        txtLetraMontada6 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada6);
        txtLetraMontada7 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada7);
        txtLetraMontada8 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada8);
        txtLetraMontada9 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada9);
        txtLetraMontada10 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada10);

        txtLetraMontada11 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada11);
        txtLetraMontada12 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada12);
        txtLetraMontada13 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada13);
        txtLetraMontada14 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada14);
        txtLetraMontada15 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada15);

        txtLetraMontada16 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada16);
        txtLetraMontada17 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada17);
        txtLetraMontada18 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada18);
        txtLetraMontada19 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada19);
        txtLetraMontada20 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada20);

        txtLetraMontada21 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada21);
        txtLetraMontada22 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada22);
        txtLetraMontada23 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada23);
        txtLetraMontada24 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada24);
        txtLetraMontada25 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada25);
        txtLetraMontada26 = findViewById(R.id.txtLetraMontada26);

        buttonLetra1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra1);
        buttonLetra2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra2);
        buttonLetra3 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra3);
        buttonLetra4 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra4);
        buttonLetra5 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra5);

        buttonLetra6 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra6);
        buttonLetra7 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra7);
        buttonLetra8 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra8);
        buttonLetra9 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra9);
        buttonLetra10 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra10);

        buttonLetra11 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra11);
        buttonLetra12 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra12);
        buttonLetra13 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra13);
        buttonLetra14 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra14);
        buttonLetra15 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra15);

        buttonLetra16 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra16);
        buttonLetra17 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra17);
        buttonLetra18 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra18);
        buttonLetra19 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra19);
        buttonLetra20 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra20);

        buttonLetra21 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra21);
        buttonLetra22 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra22);
        buttonLetra23 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra23);
        buttonLetra24 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra24);
        buttonLetra25 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra25);
        buttonLetra26 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLetra26);

        btnEmbaralhar = findViewById(R.id.btnEmbaralhar);
        btnSair = findViewById(R.id.btnSair);
        btnJogarNovamente = findViewById(R.id.btnJogarNovamente);

        zeraLetras();

          palavra = "listaNomes()";
          palavraSemEdicao = palavra.toUpperCase();
          String texto = embaralharPalavra(palavra);
          palavraEmbaralhada = texto.toUpperCase();

          colocaLetrasNosBotoes();

      }

    public String listaNomes(){

        List<String> minhaLista = Arrays.asList("dinossauro", "baixista", "lobo", "palhaco");
        posicaoLista = 0;
        nomeSelecionado = minhaLista.get(posicaoLista);
        txtPalavraCerta.setText(nomeSelecionado);
        return nomeSelecionado;
    }

    public String listaDica(){

        List<String> minhaListaDicas = Arrays.asList("animal", "profissão", "animal", "profissão");
        String dica = minhaListaDicas.get(posicaoLista);
        txtDica.setText(dica);
        return nomeSelecionado;
    }

    private String embaralharPalavra(String palavra){
        List<String> letras = Arrays.asList(palavra.split(""));
        Collections.shuffle(letras);
        String palavraEmbaralhada = "";

        for (String letra: letras){
            palavraEmbaralhada += letra;
        }

        return palavraEmbaralhada;
    }



       private void colocaLetrasNosBotoes(){
       String minhaPalavra = palavraEmbaralhada;

       letra0 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(0));
       letra1 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(1));
       letra2 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(2));
       letra3 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(3));
       letra4 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(4));

       letra5 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(5));
       letra6 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(6));
       letra7 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(7));
       letra8 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(8));
       letra9 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(9));

       letra10 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(10));
       letra11 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(11));
       letra12 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(12));
       letra13 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(13));
       letra14 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(14));

       letra15 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(15));
       letra16 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(16));
       letra17 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(17));
       letra18 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(18));
       letra19 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(19));

       letra20 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(20));
       letra21 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(21));
       letra22 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(22));
       letra23 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(23));
       letra24 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(24));
       letra25 = String.valueOf(minhaPalavra.charAt(25));

       buttonLetra1.setText(letra0);
       buttonLetra2.setText(letra1);
       buttonLetra3.setText(letra2);
       buttonLetra4.setText(letra3);
       buttonLetra5.setText(letra4);

       buttonLetra6.setText(letra5);
       buttonLetra7.setText(letra6);
       buttonLetra8.setText(letra7);
       buttonLetra9.setText(letra8);
       buttonLetra10.setText(letra9);

       buttonLetra11.setText(letra10);
       buttonLetra12.setText(letra11);
       buttonLetra13.setText(letra12);
       buttonLetra14.setText(letra13);
       buttonLetra15.setText(letra14);

       buttonLetra16.setText(letra15);
       buttonLetra17.setText(letra16);
       buttonLetra18.setText(letra17);
       buttonLetra19.setText(letra18);
       buttonLetra20.setText(letra19);

       buttonLetra21.setText(letra20);
       buttonLetra22.setText(letra21);
       buttonLetra23.setText(letra22);
       buttonLetra24.setText(letra23);
       buttonLetra25.setText(letra24);
       buttonLetra26.setText(letra25);

    }

    private void zeraLetras(){
        ClickBtn1 = "nao";
        ClickBtn2 = "nao";
        ClickBtn3 = "nao";
        ClickBtn4 = "nao";
        ClickBtn5 = "nao";

        ClickBtn6 = "nao";
        ClickBtn7 = "nao";
        ClickBtn8 = "nao";
        ClickBtn9 = "nao";
        ClickBtn10 = "nao";

        ClickBtn11 = "nao";
        ClickBtn12 = "nao";
        ClickBtn13 = "nao";
        ClickBtn14 = "nao";
        ClickBtn15 = "nao";

        ClickBtn16 = "nao";
        ClickBtn17 = "nao";
        ClickBtn18 = "nao";
        ClickBtn19 = "nao";
        ClickBtn20 = "nao";

        ClickBtn21 = "nao";
        ClickBtn22 = "nao";
        ClickBtn23 = "nao";
        ClickBtn24 = "nao";
        ClickBtn25 = "nao";
        ClickBtn26 = "nao";

        txtLetraMontada1.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada2.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada3.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada4.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada5.setText("_");

        txtLetraMontada6.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada7.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada8.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada9.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada10.setText("_");

        txtLetraMontada11.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada12.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada13.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada14.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada15.setText("_");

        txtLetraMontada16.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada17.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada18.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada19.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada20.setText("_");

        txtLetraMontada21.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada22.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada23.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada24.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada25.setText("_");
        txtLetraMontada26.setText("_");
    }```

Esse é a parte onde constam os erros no logcat:

```FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas, PID: 32690 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas/com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=12 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4164) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=12 at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method) at com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas.MainActivity.colocaLetrasNosBotoes(MainActivity.java:456) at com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas.MainActivity.novoJogo(MainActivity.java:421) at com.bygaanv.palavrasembaralhadas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146)```

agradeço a quem puder me ajudar a entender o que devo fazer para corrigir esse erro


Não repita perguntas, siga as orientações já fornecidas na pergunta original. Se precisar comentar faça na pergunta original também.
